# Trouble with Swing components

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, itemlistener

I am getting a bunch of errors in Java, I don't know where to begin. I am new to GUI programming and would greatly appreciate any help you could provide or even just a nudge in the right direction.

Here is my current code:

```
// DebugFourteen2
// Displays list of payment options
// - credit card, check or cash
// Displays fee for using each - 5%, 2% or 0%
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DebugFourteen2 extends JFrame implements ItemListener {
    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
    JComboBox payMethod = new JComboBox();
    JLabel payList = new JLabel("Pay List");
    JTextField totFees = new JTextField(25);
    String pctMsg = new String("per cent will be added to your bill");
    int[] fees = {5, 2, 0};
    int feePct = 0;
    String output;
    int fee = 0;

    public void DebugFourteen2() {
        super("Pay List");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(flow);
        payMethod.addItemListener();
        add(payList);
        add(payMethod);
        payMethod.addItem("Credit card");
        payMethod.addItem("Check");
        payMethod.addItem("Cash");
        add(totFees);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        JFrame cframe = new DebugFourteen2();
        cframe.setSize(350, 150);
        cframe.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent list) {
        Object source = list.getSource();
        if (source = payMethod)
            int fee = payMethod.getSelectedIndex();
        feePct = fees[x];
        output = feePct + " " + pctMsg;
        totFees.setText(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to include the errors.

Comment: Always provide a proper code formatting to keep your code clean and readable. If need some help with the formatting on Stackoverflow, then read this help page please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

There you go, it compiles and you can run it (use my code below): OUTPUT:

[image]

You have so many mistakes .. (probably this is a homework which asks you to fix this code which doesn't compile):

1)
    ">`"
at first line. no java code can compile having this line

2)

```
payMethod.addItemListener();
```

should be changed to `payMethod.addItemListener(this);` or else the listener does not work in java..

3) `feePct = fees[x];` should be changed to `feePct = fees[fee];` because quite simply `x` does not exist in your code...

4) **`** at the last line.. no java program will ever run with this character at the end of a class...

5) As @Tom mentioned in his comment, this is wrong and unnecessary `int fee = payMethod.getSelectedIndex();` . You already declared `int fee = 0;` you do not need (and can not because it is a mistake) re-declare it as `int fee = payMethod.getSelectedIndex();` .. just `fee = payMethod.getSelectedIndex();` is enough

```
    // DebugFourteen2
// Displays list of payment options
// - credit card, check or cash
// Displays fee for using each - 5%, 2% or 0%
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class DebugFourteen2 extends JFrame implements ItemListener
{
    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
    JComboBox payMethod = new JComboBox();
    JLabel payList = new JLabel("Pay List");
    JTextField totFees = new JTextField(25);
    String pctMsg = new String("per cent will be added to your bill");
    int[] fees = {5,2,0};
    int feePct = 0;
    String output;
    int fee = 0;
public DebugFourteen2()
{
//super("Pay List");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(flow);
    payMethod.addItemListener(this);
    add(payList);
    add(payMethod);
    payMethod.addItem("Credit card");
    payMethod.addItem("Check");
    payMethod.addItem("Cash");
    add(totFees);
}
public static void main(String[] arguments)
{
    JFrame cframe = new DebugFourteen2();
    cframe.setSize(350, 150);
    cframe.setVisible(true);
}
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent list)
{
    Object source = list.getSource();
    if(source == payMethod)
    fee = payMethod.getSelectedIndex();
    feePct = fees[fee];
    output = feePct + " " + pctMsg;
    totFees.setText(output);
}
}
```

Comment: @Point 1 and 4: these are obviously formatting characters. OP tried to format his code but made some mistakes.

Comment: Just did, hope it is better now :)

Comment: It is. Thanks. Btw: you corrected it already, but you should also explain why the variable type is wrong here: `int fee = payMethod.getSelectedIndex();`.

Comment: Thanks. just changed it .. so many mistakes (probably a HW :D) that I forgot some of the things I did :D

Answer (score 0):

I will add some comments to explain the changes that I've made:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class DebugFourteen2 extends JFrame implements ItemListener {
    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
    JComboBox payMethod = new JComboBox();
    JLabel payList = new JLabel("Pay List");
    JTextField totFees = new JTextField(25);
    String pctMsg = new String("per cent will be added to your bill");
    int[] fees = {5,2,0};
    int feePct = 0;
    String output;
    int fee = 0;
    //public void DebugFourteen2(){
       // super("Pay List");  you can use super in this context because
        // DebugFourteen2 is a method, remove the 'void' to make it a constructor
     public  DebugFourteen2(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(flow);
        //payMethod.addItemListener(); you need to pass an 'ItemListener' to this method
        payMethod.addItemListener(this);
        add(payList);
        add(payMethod);
        payMethod.addItem("Credit card");
        payMethod.addItem("Check");
        payMethod.addItem("Cash");
        add(totFees);
    }
    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        JFrame cframe = new DebugFourteen2();
        cframe.setSize(350, 150);
        cframe.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent list){
        Object source = list.getSource();
        //if(source = payMethod)// in Java you compere Objects using `==` instead of `=`
        if(source == payMethod){
            int fee = payMethod.getSelectedIndex();
            //feePct = fees[x];  there is no variable `x` probably you meant to use `fee` here
            feePct = fees[fee];
            output = feePct + " " + pctMsg;
            totFees.setText(output);
        }
    }
}
```